# Angular: How to use router in angular unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test case in angular. I have written a condition if `res.length === 1` redirect to the details page. (`this.router.navigate(['details', id])`). I'm getting the `id` from the first array of the object in body response as `const id = res[0].id`. These both line are not covered in my code coverage. Can anyone let me know where I made mistake?

I'm getting `Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ '/product-details', 'SAAASD0001' ] ] but it was never called.`

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
let router = {navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')};
```

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: Router, useValue: router }
  ]
})
```

```
it('should take data from store', () => {
  const mockData = [
      {
        id: '123',
        name: 'Stackoverlow',
      }
  ]
  expect(component.getList).toEqual(mockData);

  const productId = mockData[0].id;
  expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/details', id]);
});
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  getList() {
    this.store
      .select('content', 'catalogue')
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        Iif (res.length === 1) {
          // this line doesn't cover
          const id = res[0].id;
          // this line doesn't cover
          this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
        } else {
          this.list = category(res);
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: can you post the declaration of `routerSpy`?

Comment: @alexortizl sorry. Updated. It supposed to be `router`

Comment: When are you calling the getList() method?  You seem to be missing the ()

Comment: @satchcoder hmm that's not an issue. issue is how i can cover router code in testing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Router` and `Store` public in component and try:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  providers: [Router,Store ]
})

it('should take data from store', () => {
  const response = [{id: 'val'}];
  spyOn(component.store,"select").and.returnValue(of(response));
  spyOn(component.router,"navigate").and.callThrough();
  component.getList();
  expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/details', response[0].id]);
});
```

similarly cover `else`part by changing `const response = [{id: 'val'}];`

Answer (score 0):

Add this thing to your imports :

```
 RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: 'path1', component: TestComponent1},
          { path: 'home', component: DashboardComponent }
        ]),
```

later on in your test case : you can spy on "Navigate" of Router and and use it for redirection to any component mentioned in imports.

```
spyOn(Router,"navigate").and.callthrough();
router.navigate([/path1]);
```